# Put an array of int into a char. C or C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying something very simple (I think), outputting into a char an array of int, something like this:

```
 int Z[10]={0};
 char buff[100];

 for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
    Z[i]+=10;
  }

   sprintf(buff,"%d",Z); 
 retunr buff;
```

I hope you can helpme or giving an alternative solution.

How can i put all of those values(of the int array) in a single varible?

Best regards.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Voting to close, but if you edit this and ask a clear question I'll remove my vote.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: C or C++: very different answers depending.

Comment: What do you want `buff` to contain?

Comment: Do you want to put _each_ entry in `Z` in the string?

Comment: @Mike Who knows what will end up in `buff` with this code.  It has undefined behavior.

Comment: there was someone who posted and deleted a method using memcpy, I'ld
love to try that one too.

Comment: @Mike First, there is _never_ an implicit conversion of a pointer to `int`.  You need a `reinterpret_cast`.  And second, how is the compiler to know that the function is expecting an `int`.  When passing an argument to a `...`, the _only_ conversions are the integral promotions.

Comment: @Joaquin The poster probably deleted it because it doesn't work.  You end up with random gibberish in `buffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have provided shouldn't work fine, since `Z` is an array of `int`, whereas `%d` involves an `int`. using `sprintf`, it is possible to put each value of `Z` in a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int size = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  size += sprintf(buff+size, "%d", Z[i]);
}
```

Comment: Same comment as for Jay's solution.  It's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(buff,"%d",Z);
```

is wrong. Your idea is to literally put the entire array into the buffer, which doesn't work.

It should be

```
int ret = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  ret += sprintf(buff+ret, "%d", z[i]);
}
```

The code snippet is just an example. Please ensure you do sufficient error checks.

Another suggestion is to use [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) which is a safer alternative to sprintf.

Comment: This solution will end up with either a single, very, very large number in the buffer, or buffer overflow (and undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't* use `sprintf`.  It's far too dangerous.  Second,
don't forget the separators.  Something like:

```
std::ostringstream dest;
for ( int const* p = std::begin( Z ); p != std::end( Z ); ++ p ) {
    if ( p != std::begin( Z ) ) {
        dest << ' ';
    }
    dest << *p;
}
std::string results = dest.str();
```

Should do the trick.